# nmap output Failed to open normal output file n for writing

Tags: file, text, output, nmap

when I execute using zenmap command, I get the error, Failed to open normal output file n for writing QUITTING!

How can I write the scan result to a file?

```sh
nmap -oN n "c:\\temp\\scan1.txt" 192.168.1.2
```

Answer (score 3):

According to this quote from the manual:

```
OUTPUT:
  -oN/-oX/-oS/-oG <file>: Output scan in normal, XML, s|<rIpt kIddi3,
     and Grepable format, respectively, to the given filename.
```

It appears that the file designation should be placed immediately following the `oN` (ie, without the intervening `n`).

Comment: thanks - for some reason that N was automatically inserted when I type in the command, but for some reason this time it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your directory and folder names are correct. This happens when you try to save the output file and path you gave does not exist or match.

Answer (score 0):

try to first go to the directory on command line, then run the command with just name of the text like in the following;
nmap -oN scan.txt scanme.nmap.org

Answer (score 0):

Just place a " - " before writing an target IP address

command:-sudo nmap -oG 192.168.18.0/24 -vv 
result:-Failed to open machine output file 192.168.18.0/24 for writing
QUITTING!

  after placing " - " before writing IP address

command:-sudo nmap -oG - 192.168.18.0/24 -vv
result:-# Nmap 7.91 scan initiated Wed Aug 25 15:22:58 2021 as: nmap -oG - -vv 192.168.18.0/24 
#Ports scanned: TCP(1000;1,3-4,6-7,9,13,17,19-26,30,32-33,37,42-43,49,53,70,79-85,88-90,99-100,106,109-111,113,119,125,135,139,143-144,146,161,163,179,199,211-212,222,254-256,259,264,280,301,306,311,340,366,389,406-407,416-417,425,427,443-445,458,464-465,481,497,500,512-515,524,541,543-545,548,554-555,563,587,593,616-617,625,631,636,646,648,666-668,683,687,691,700,705,711,714,720,722,726,749,765,777,783,787,800-801,808,843,873,880,888,898,900-903,911-912,981,987,990,992-993,995,999-1002,1007,1009-1011,1021-1100,1102,1104-1108,1110-1114,1117,1119,1121.............................................................................................................................